# How to find the exact same element as the one on the page in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I need to find an element in an iframe that is the exact same element of that that is in the webpage (the iframe is of the same page). I need to figure out what the index is of the elements without id's with jquery so I can get the same element in an iframe.

Edit: How can I find the index of an element?

i.e. for this html:

```
<div>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a id="someA">4</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <a>7</a>
</div>
```

How would I find the index (so I can it by doing `$('a')[index]`) of one of the random anchor elements from it's jQuery object?

(By doing `$('#someA').siblings()[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)].getIndex()`)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YP5hQ/2/

Comment: Don't use a link to an external site for your code or sample data. *WHEN* that link breaks your question will be fairly worthless to others. Add your sample code and data to your question by editing it.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question

Comment: What do you mean, "the exact same element"? By content, id, class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_barzilay/ZB2vE/

But you got the function all wrong.. i suggest that you will learn about: [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) and [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

***notice that i havn't used any native javascript**. it's no need when you have the wonderfull *jQuery* :)

**I changed this line: `$(elem).html(c);` to this: `$(elem).html(h);` because i thought you ment to do it with `h` if not simply change the `h` with an `c`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function, it basically takes an element and works backwards to see it's exact path. I didn't use it for what you are planning, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

```
function mirrorpath ( elm ) {
  /// add an indentifying segment to the path for each parent element
  var addtopath = function( elm ){
    var node = $(elm), ident = '';
    /// first off, add our nodeName to our identity
    ident += node.get(0).nodeName;
    /// if we have an id, then we are specific enough
    if ( node.attr('id') ) {
      ident += '#' + node.attr('id');
    }
    /// otherwise
    else{
      /// if we have a class, that's good :)
      if ( node.attr('class') ) {
        ident += '.' + node.attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
      }
      /// now make it more accurate with an index offset
      ident += ':eq('+node.prevAll(ident).add(node).index(node)+')';
    }
    /// add our new path segment
    path.push( ident );
  }
  /// step through the target elements parents and build our path
  var parents = $(elm).parents().get(), path = [], i = parents.length;
  while ( i-- ) { addtopath( parents[i] ); }; addtopath( elm );
  /// implode the path and return
  return path.join(' ');
}
```

The returned path should evaluate and find your elements on both the main page and the iframe - all you have to do is feed the path back into jQuery. I have to confess your question is a rather odd request ;)

ps. I haven't tested this code across very complexly deep elements, so there may be certain situations where it fails... It could also probably be optimised by not using an array for the path storage (<del>*and foolishly rejoining on each iteration...*</del> *I've just updated the code to optimise this problem away)* but thanks to jQuery and Sizzle it's worked for everything I've needed it for so far.

### edit / update

Just in case this is useful, I decided to revamp the code a little for myself and turn it in to a jQuery plugin. There are a few optimisations in place now with regards to the generation of the actual css path, and optimistaions on how the path will fare when parsed by jQuery.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.cssPath = function () {
    var paths = [], addtopath = function( elm ){
      if ( elm && (elm.nodeName || (elm instanceof $ && elm.length)) ) {
        var node = $(elm), ident = String(node.get(0).nodeName).toLowerCase();
        /// if we have an id, then we are specific enough
        if ( node.attr('id') ) {
          ident += '#' + node.attr('id');
        }
        /// otherwise
        else{
          /// if we have a class, that's good :)
          if ( node.attr('class') ) {
            ident += '.' + node.attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
          };
          /// make sure there is a point to being more specific (leads to nicer paths)
          if ( node.siblings(ident).length > 0 ) {
            /// now make it more accurate with an index offset
            //ident += ':eq('+node.prevAll(ident).add(node).index(node)+')';
            ident += ':nth-child('+(node.index()+1)+')';
          };
        };
        /// add our new path segment
        return ident;
      };
    };
    this.each(function(){
      /// find the parents for this element, and add the current element to the list
      var parents = $(this).parents().get(), path = '', i = parents.unshift(this) && parents.length;
      /// build up the path string per parent
      while ( i-- ) { path += (path ? ' > ' : '') + addtopath( parents[i] ); };
      /// return the path to our paths list
      paths.push(path);
    });
    /// if one path, return string, if more return array
    return ( paths.length > 1 ? paths : paths[0] );
  }
})((typeof jQuery != undefined) && jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
var path = $('#my_target_element').cssPath();
```

Example output:

```
html > body > div#BlogArchive1 > ul.hierarchy > li.archivedate.expanded > a
```